# Node.js - Server is not a constructor() ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am creating a node server. I have declared a server class and in the constructor i am calling listen on the express app. Then i am exporting this Server class.

> const instance = new Server();
>                    ^ TypeError: Server is not a constructor

**index.js**

```
const Server = require("./server");
const instance = new Server();
exports.default = instance.server;
```

**server.js**

```
const App = require("./app");

class Server {

    constructor() {

        this.app = new App();
        this.instance = this.app.instance;
        this.config = this.app.config;
        this.server = this.instance.listen(this.config.port, "0.0.0.0");

        console.log("Server Running On: 0.0.0.0:" + this.config.port);

    }

}

exports.default = Server;
```

**webpack**

```
const path = require("path");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require("webpack-shell-plugin");

module.exports = {

    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    target: "node",
    devtool: "source-map",

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "index.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "index.js.map"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    "plugins": [
        new WebpackShellPlugin({ onBuildEnd: ["nodemon dist/index.js"] }),
    ]

};
```

**npm**

```
**    "serve": "webpack --watch",
```

Comment: Try changing exports.default to just exports. You are assigning your export to "default" so otherwise you would need to do `new Server.default()`, you should see this if you console.log the export.

Answer (score 7):

You're using `require`, that is [node modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and not [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

The "default" export is the complete `module.exports`.

Replace

```
exports.default = Server;
```

with

```
module.exports = Server;
```

Comment: I see so if i were to switch `const Server = require("./server");` to `import Server from "./server"` how could i export that?